# Spotting review audits

Tags: discussion, review-audits

I've recently started reviewing posts and I think the idea behind auditing reviewers is a good idea so as to keep things consistent.

However, during my review sessions, I've noticed that you can quite often spot the audit questions specifically due to a few giveaways with the data.

A couple of examples I've seen recently of "spottable" audits:

- Username/rep missing (for some answers)
- thousands of views on a question that was posted "today"

In each of these cases would it not be better for some false data to be implemented so a more accurate audit test could be done?

I Know that in general for the audits false data is indeed given, but allowing a reviewer to view the original question in the live environment would kinda detracts from the audit somewhat, no?

Comment: Despite such audits being easy to spot they still catch robo-reviewers in their multitudes so it's not actually necessary to make them any more accurate.

Comment: related on MSO: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287670/review-audits-exploitable-able-to-see-real-review-stats-before-voting-on-the-re/287852#287852

Comment: @rene Thank you, thats the exact thing i was looking for.

Comment: Audits are there to catch people who don't pay attention.  Audits are easy to spot when you're paying attention.  You're spotting them because you're paying attention.  I don't see any problems here.